# Actionscript 3.0 - incrementing a text file

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, text, storage

I am looking for a quick and easy way to store variables in a text file, rather than use amfphp to connect to a database all I need to do is increment values every time a button is clicked .

Would be better if all the vars were in the same text file but if I have to have one per var that would be ok.

Comment: Where are you intending to save your files, on your server or the user's computer?

Answer (score 1):

If your app is a desktop one, you can user AIR's File and FileStream classes in APPEND mode, like this:

```
        // create the file reference
        var file:File = File.documentsDirectory; 
        file = file.resolvePath("air_tests/saved_by_AIR.txt");

        // create a stream object to read/write, and open in in APPEND mode
        var stream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
        stream.open(file, FileMode.APPEND);

        // add a new line to the text file
        stream.writeUTFBytes( (new Date()).toString() + "\n" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Desktop apps can use AIR's File and FileStream classes.

See protozoo's example for that.

However, if encryption is necessary, use the [`EncryptedLocalStore`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=EncryptedLocalStore_1.html) class.

```
var myVar:int=100; //This is what you'll increemnt.
var bytesToWrite:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
bytesToWrite.writeInt(myVar);
EncryptedLocalStore.setItem("myVar", bytesToWrite);
```

To retreive the value,

```
var storedValue:ByteArray = EncryptedLocalStore.getItem("myVar");
var readVar:int=storedValue.readInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to save a file without a file dialog popping up (perhaps in AIR, but I haven't tested it), so this can quickly get annoying. If it's only for internal use - as in you don't need to access it outside of flash - then check out the SharedObject class instead: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html

Works pretty much like a normal Object, it's just persisted over multiple plays